# Cannot route from a http request to a https request using the spring cloud gateway

Tags: ssl, spring-cloud, tls1.2, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to route all http requests to a https service using the spring cloud gateway but always receive a handshake_failure.

Routing everything to https://google.com for example works, but to my own service with its private certificate, created and signed by my own private CA, it does not, although I provided the matching truststore via `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` and set `useInsecureTrustManager: true`. So what is wrong here?

My spring cloud gateway config:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8081}
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
      routes:
        - id: after_route
          uri: https://my.server:2900/server/ping
          predicates:
            - After=2017-01-20T17:42:47.789-07:00[America/Denver]
```

And the log out put with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`:

```
2019-07-30 14:14:27.206  INFO 8257 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddc24342] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-07-30 14:14:27.315  INFO 8257 --- [           main] com.tobias.gateway.Gateway               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-07-30 14:14:27.704  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=90eb380c-f88b-3401-b688-6ef3ead8e5f1
2019-07-30 14:14:27.724  INFO 8257 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddc24342] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:27.950 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:427|System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:27.953 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:427|System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:27.974 CEST|SSLCipher.java:437|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:27.984 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:401|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:27.984 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:410|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
...
... Lots of other ignored cipher suites
...
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.009 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: truststore.jks
trustStore type is: pkcs12
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Wed Apr 10 10:36:03 CEST 2019
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.009 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:311|Reload the trust store
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.022 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:318|Reload trust certs
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.022 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:323|Reloaded 1 trust certs
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.026 CEST|X509TrustManagerImpl.java:79|adding as trusted certificates (
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 E0 97 A2 3A FB A3 C1 44",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "EMAILADDRESS=my@e.mail, CN=My Root Certificate Authority, OU=My OU, O=Me, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE",
    "not before"         : "2018-10-05 13:38:39.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2023-10-04 13:38:39.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "EMAILADDRESS=my@e.mail, CN=My Root Certificate Authority, OU=My OU, O=Me, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 87 FB AB 07 09 69 28 5C   53 05 29 49 44 B1 5C C7  .....i(\S.)ID.\.
        0010: E2 A3 54 22                                        ..T"
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 87 FB AB 07 09 69 28 5C   53 05 29 49 44 B1 5C C7  .....i(\S.)ID.\.
        0010: E2 A3 54 22                                        ..T"
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.026 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:115|trigger seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.026 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:119|done seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.040 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: truststore.jks
trustStore type is: pkcs12
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Wed Apr 10 10:36:03 CEST 2019
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.041 CEST|X509TrustManagerImpl.java:79|adding as trusted certificates (
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 E0 97 A2 3A FB A3 C1 44",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "EMAILADDRESS=my@e.mail, CN=My Root Certificate Authority, OU=My OU, O=Me, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE",
    "not before"         : "2018-10-05 13:38:39.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2023-10-04 13:38:39.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "EMAILADDRESS=my@e.mail, CN=My Root Certificate Authority, OU=My OU, O=Me, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 87 FB AB 07 09 69 28 5C   53 05 29 49 44 B1 5C C7  .....i(\S.)ID.\.
        0010: E2 A3 54 22                                        ..T"
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 87 FB AB 07 09 69 28 5C   53 05 29 49 44 B1 5C C7  .....i(\S.)ID.\.
        0010: E2 A3 54 22                                        ..T"
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.041 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:115|trigger seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.042 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:119|done seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.048 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: truststore.jks
trustStore type is: pkcs12
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Wed Apr 10 10:36:03 CEST 2019
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.049 CEST|X509TrustManagerImpl.java:79|adding as trusted certificates (
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 E0 97 A2 3A FB A3 C1 44",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "EMAILADDRESS=my@e.mail, CN=My Root Certificate Authority, OU=My OU, O=Me, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE",
    "not before"         : "2018-10-05 13:38:39.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2023-10-04 13:38:39.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "EMAILADDRESS=my@e.mail, CN=My Root Certificate Authority, OU=My OU, O=Me, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 87 FB AB 07 09 69 28 5C   53 05 29 49 44 B1 5C C7  .....i(\S.)ID.\.
        0010: E2 A3 54 22                                        ..T"
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 87 FB AB 07 09 69 28 5C   53 05 29 49 44 B1 5C C7  .....i(\S.)ID.\.
        0010: E2 A3 54 22                                        ..T"
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.049 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:115|trigger seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.049 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:119|done seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.055 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: truststore.jks
trustStore type is: pkcs12
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Wed Apr 10 10:36:03 CEST 2019
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.056 CEST|X509TrustManagerImpl.java:79|adding as trusted certificates (
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 E0 97 A2 3A FB A3 C1 44",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "EMAILADDRESS=my@e.mail, CN=My Root Certificate Authority, OU=My OU, O=Me, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE",
    "not before"         : "2018-10-05 13:38:39.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2023-10-04 13:38:39.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "EMAILADDRESS=my@e.mail, CN=My Root Certificate Authority, OU=My OU, O=Me, L=Hamburg, ST=Hamburg, C=DE",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 87 FB AB 07 09 69 28 5C   53 05 29 49 44 B1 5C C7  .....i(\S.)ID.\.
        0010: E2 A3 54 22                                        ..T"
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 87 FB AB 07 09 69 28 5C   53 05 29 49 44 B1 5C C7  .....i(\S.)ID.\.
        0010: E2 A3 54 22                                        ..T"
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.056 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:115|trigger seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.056 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:119|done seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.068 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:115|trigger seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2019-07-30 14:14:28.068 CEST|SSLContextImpl.java:119|done seeding of SecureRandom
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [After]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Before]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Between]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Cookie]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Header]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Host]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Method]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Path]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Query]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [ReadBodyPredicateFactory]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [RemoteAddr]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Weight]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.408  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [CloudFoundryRouteService]
2019-07-30 14:14:28.828  INFO 8257 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8081
2019-07-30 14:14:28.832  INFO 8257 --- [           main] com.tobias.gateway.Gateway               : Started Gateway in 2.114 seconds (JVM running for 2.72)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.298 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.298 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.298 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.299 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.299 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.299 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.308 CEST|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:841|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe2048
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.309 CEST|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:841|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe3072
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.309 CEST|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:841|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe4096
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.309 CEST|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:841|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe6144
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.309 CEST|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:841|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe8192
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.313 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:282|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.314 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:282|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|ALL|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.317 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:358|Ignore disabled signature sheme: rsa_md5
javax.net.ssl|INFO|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.317 CEST|AlpnExtension.java:161|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.317 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:256|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.318 CEST|ClientHello.java:651|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "BC 92 B0 0D 8A 40 3B CD E7 64 2D 46 A3 49 24 55 08 48 3A BC 02 B3 31 89 20 B2 F3 68 32 AF C4 82",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [

  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.329 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:507|WRITE: TLS12 handshake, length = 260
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.330 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:525|Raw write (
  0000: 16 03 03 01 04 01 00 01   00 03 03 BC 92 B0 0D 8A  ................
  0010: 40 3B CD E7 64 2D 46 A3   49 24 55 08 48 3A BC 02  @;..d-F.I$U.H:..
  0020: B3 31 89 20 B2 F3 68 32   AF C4 82 00 00 10 C0 2C  .1. ..h2.......,
  0030: C0 2B C0 2F C0 13 C0 14   00 9C 00 2F 00 35 01 00  .+./......./.5..
  0040: 00 C7 00 00 00 21 00 1F   00 00 1C 70 6C 61 79 67  .....!.....playg
  0050: 72 6F 75 6E 64 2E 6D 61   63 68 69 6E 65 73 2E 6E  round.machines.n
  0060: 37 6C 61 62 2E 69 6F 00   05 00 05 01 00 00 00 00  7lab.io.........
  0070: 00 0A 00 16 00 14 00 17   00 18 00 19 00 09 00 0A  ................
  0080: 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00 0E   00 16 00 0B 00 02 01 00  ................
  0090: 00 0D 00 28 00 26 04 03   05 03 06 03 08 04 08 05  ...(.&..........
  00A0: 08 06 08 09 08 0A 08 0B   04 01 05 01 06 01 04 02  ................
  00B0: 03 03 03 01 03 02 02 03   02 01 02 02 00 32 00 28  .............2.(
  00C0: 00 26 04 03 05 03 06 03   08 04 08 05 08 06 08 09  .&..............
  00D0: 08 0A 08 0B 04 01 05 01   06 01 04 02 03 03 03 01  ................
  00E0: 03 02 02 03 02 01 02 02   00 11 00 09 00 07 02 00  ................
  00F0: 04 00 00 00 00 00 17 00   00 00 2B 00 07 06 03 03  ..........+.....
  0100: 03 02 03 01 FF 01 00 01   00                       .........
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.357 CEST|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:177|Raw read (
  0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.358 CEST|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.359 CEST|Alert.java:232|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|29|reactor-http-nio-6|2019-07-30 14:14:36.360 CEST|TransportContext.java:313|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:627)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:422)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:295)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1332)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:682)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:617)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:534)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)}

)
```

Comment: I debugged a little and can see that in the case of routing to google.com the gateway steps through the ```InsecureTrustManagerFactory.checkClientTrusted()``` method while it does not if it shall route to my own service.

Is this because that step will only be made after the handshake? Is my certificate somehow out of order, although all my other clients are able to connect to the service with that certificate?

Comment: No using a certificate from letsencrypt does not help either. It must be something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer after playing around with the server ssl configuration. The service that I route to ist a spring boot application and its ssl config restricts the cipher suites to use like this:

`server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`

And that suite can not be handled by the spring cloud gateway. If I do not set that property at all, it works.

But now I would like to know what suites the spring cloud gateway supports? And why is that a problem of the gateway at all?